# Does Rocket Robin Hood steal from the "cosmic", "astral" or other rich?

Tags: rocket-robin-hood

In the voice over at the start of the cartoon series [*Rocket Robin Hood*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0135735/) (last time I saw it was approx 1972!) The narrator says, I think, one of the following...

> He steals from the ASTRAL rich to give to the COSMIC poor.
>
> He steals from the COSMIC rich to give to the  ASTRAL poor.

I've looked on Google and YouTube but no luck, maybe not doing a decent search string. It could be from the end and not the start but I know it was said every episode.

Can anyone enlighten please? I was trying to tell grandson about the cartoon series and couldn't get this phrase right.

Comment: I took a look on YouTube, and didn't see either phrase in what little I was able to watch. I will say this: I will never mock Hanna-Barbera production values again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the segment you're asking about goes like this (bolding mine):

> Soaring through the far reaches of interplanetary space, his new Sherwood Forest asteroid, fantastic headquarters of that swashbuckling cosmic highwayman of the 30th century, Rocket Robin Hood.
>
> Yes, here comes the one and only Rocket Robin Hood, gliding through galaxies in his search for star-shattering adventure. The interplanetary villains quiver in their space boots when they hear the merry ring of his laughter and feel the blast of his mighty electro-quarterstaff.
>
> Rocket Robin Hood, fun-loving astral adventurer in the astonishing years to come.
>
> Rocket Robin Hood, the happy outlaw of interplanetary space, is a direct descendant of Robin Hood of old. He's fast with a joyful laugh, a ready jest, and a quiverful of futuristic arrows, **Robin robs from the cosmic rich to give to the astral poor**.
>   He's fun.
>   He's fantastic.
>
> Rocket Robin Hood, the merriest of the Merry Men, in the astounding year 3000.

Comment: :-D You owe me 15 minutes of my life back for transcribing that...

Comment: well worth that fifteen minutes don't you agree!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I'm laughing because you didn't press the "transcribe" button and get youtube to do it for you

Comment: I... hadn't even really realized that existed.

Comment: :-D Although that would have been hilarious... have you seen what they auto-generate?